# How do I fix 'jQuery draggable is not a function' in AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, draggable

I have created a custom directive in AngularJS but it produces an error.

Here is my code:

```js
myApp.directive("dragMe", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'dragMe.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".dummy").draggable()
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
})
```

On adding this directive I am receiving an error:

> draggable is not a function

I have added the jQuery file in the main HTML file and added it before the angular file. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you included jqueryUI in your project?

Comment: `draggable()` is a method of jQueryUI, not standard jQuery. You need to include both libraries.

Comment: you are correct...so stupid of me....Thanks a lot..and sorry for asking such a question

Comment: @Sumeetkumar Nothing wrong with your question. It's defiantly not a stupid one

Answer (score 0):

This is caused when you don't also include the jQuery UI library.  [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) isn't part of core jQuery, it's part of the UI extensions.

Add jQuery UI below the jQuery reference and you'll be fine.